# Couldn't access input with jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xpath

I am trying to capture click event on the checkbox. Xpath for the element from the firebug is as follow where table is the starting tag for my JSP (i.e. table is inserted div)

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]/center/input
```

and html tag is

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" class="rmvChkBox" value="something"/>
```

I think since its deep inside the various elements I am not able to point to the element. 
I tried various combination few of them are

```
$('.rmvChkBox').click(function() { ... }

$('#myTable input[type=checkbox]').click(function() { ... });

$('#myTable tr td input[type=checkbox]').click(function() { ... });
```

Comment: did you try to output anything on console when clicking on checkbox??

Comment: Do u assign the click handler when DOM is ready (e.g. in `$(document).ready( )`

Comment: wrap the function within $(function(){});

Comment: works fine http://jsfiddle.net/9dg7tgsp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try another option:

```
$('input name["rmvChkBox"]').click(function() { ... });
```

this will catch all the inputs with the name "rmvChkBox".
if this doesn't work is it possible this element is appended dynamically to the dom?
if so your click wouldn't register as the element doesn't exist yet.
if this is the case you can use the "on" event or the "live" event if your in an earlier version.